# Android map Marker size and user location smooth movement

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I'm doing an app with a map and i got 2 issue:

1) I'm displaying user location with `setMyLocationEnabled(true)`, but on location change it don't get a smooth movement, but only a change position, now there is a way to add smooth movement to user location loaded by map with `setMyLocationEnabled(true)`? if not i guess need to use a custom marker on user current location, but where i can find the marker used by google with blue circle and arrow and how to get heading rotation?

2) I' m displaying markers on specific place, but when i reduce zoom their size don't change, i'd like to display markers size based on zoom, how can i do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For 2 -> You could use some hack to change the location pin when camera changes (using a drawable with the sizes proportional with zoom level), but this implies a lot of ui changes that may result in a lagging map. However, you may consider the clustering functionality https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering . Have a look and tell me what you think and if you are not pleased I will try the drawable hack

Comment: Any opinions about my comment? Also, can you add the manifest file, please?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can run a thread with time delay to change the marker
2. Use the custom icons for markers

code is below:

```
 int height = 40;
    int width = 40;

    BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
    Bitmap b = bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
    smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
```

Comment: 1) the problem is that there is no function to change position of user location marker, it is positioned and moved by Map Api

Comment: You can only hide or show  the google map marker.if you want customize the marker design and size create a custom marker and set maker in the lat,land value which you received in on location changed..[link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker)